# How to call mulitple functions onclick with return types?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

How to call mulitple functions onclick with return types?

```
<html:submit property="submit"  value="GetDetails"
  onclick="return checkYear();return getStudentDetails();" />
```

`checkYear()` checks if academic year is valid and `getStudentDetails()` gets student details from database.

```
function getStudentDetails() 
{
    if(document.forms[0].ac_year1.value==""  || document.forms[0].ac_year1.value=="0"){
        alert("Academic Year Required");
        document.forms[0].ac_year1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.forms[0].appl_id.value == ""|| document.forms[0].appl_id.value == null)
     {
        alert("Please enter the application number");
        document.forms[0].appl_id.focus();
        return false;
    }
     else 
     {
        document.forms[0].type.value = "getApplication";
        return true;
    }
}

function checkYear()
{
    if(document.forms[0].ac_year1.value!="" && document.forms[0].ac_year1.value!=0 && document.forms[0].appl_id.value!="" && document.forms[0].appl_id.value!="0")
    {
        var year=document.forms[0].ac_year1.value.substring(0,4);
        var app=document.forms[0].appl_id.value.substring(0,4);
        if(year!=app)
        {
            alert("Application Number and Academic Year mismatch");
            document.forms[0].appl_id.focus();
            document.forms[0].appl_id.value="";
            return false();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It works with   onclick="return checkYear() && getStudentDetails();"
```

**Edits**
1) Adding else { return true; }    case in checkYear()

2) replacing return false() with return false in checkYear() function

Answer (score 1):

You current implementation is incorrect, the function `getStudentDetails()` will never get executed.

However, You can use `&&`

```
onclick="return checkYear() && getStudentDetails();"
```

In above statement if `checkYear()` evaluates to *truthy* then `getStudentDetails()` will get executed.

Comment: it doesn't work page is getting submitted :( @Satpal

Comment: @DragonWarrior, Try with `onsubmit` event of `form`